# While loop ignoring my parameters. Basic below 10 above zero

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Hey guys just looking over some past assignments and i cant figure out why my while loop wont work. I need to take a input and enter a number between 1 and 10. The problem is the while loop only validates entries  outside the parameters

```
int n;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
  System.out.print("Enter number 1&10");
  n = sc.nextInt();
}

while (n>=1 && n<=10);

System.out.print("Validated number = "+ n);
```

Comment: `while (n>=1 && n<=10)` means that it will continue repeating as long as `n` is between 1 and 10 inclusive. You probably meant `while (n < 1 || n > 10)`, which will only repeat when it's outside of that range.

Comment: Ah dam im to tired buddy, thanks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is saying "Keep iterating while the value is *in* the range we want." Surely you want to keep asking the user for more input while the value is *outside* the range you want:

```java
do {
  System.out.print("Enter number 1&10");
  n = sc.nextInt();
} while (n < 1 || n > 10);
```

Always think about what the condition is intended to represent, and remember that the loop will keep going if the condition is *true*.